# Spring Cloud Data Flow Aggregator processor won't start

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to deploy a test stream using the app starter aggregator processor.
Just using the default settings, the processor aggregator doesn't start, I have no log, readiness and liveness probes fail.
My SCDF is deployed on a minikube and using bitnami chart version 2.11.3.
What would be a minimum configuration for the aggregator processor to start properly?

Comment: I answer to my own question. Aggregator processor version 3.0.1 and 3.0.2 failed but trying version 2.1.6-BUILD-SNAPHOT it works as I expected.